# failed to download Mojo SDK

Tags: mojolang

I'm using WSL.

the install command:

```
root@ALL:~# curl https://get.modular.com |   MODULAR_AUTH=mut_c38ba851f1854399b827e0293451c24a   sh -
```

download process:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3176  100  3176    0     0   3580      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3576
```

```
Executing the  setup script for the 'modular/installer' repository ...
OK: Checking for required executable 'curl' ...
OK: Checking for required executable 'apt-get' ...
OK: Detecting your OS distribution and release using system methods ...
^^^^: ... Detected/provided for your OS/distribution, version and architecture:
>>>>:
>>>>: ... distro=ubuntu  version=20.04  codename=focal  arch=x86_64  
>>>>:
OK: Checking for apt dependency 'apt-transport-https' ...
OK: Checking for apt dependency 'ca-certificates' ...
OK: Checking for apt dependency 'gnupg' ...
RUN: Importing 'modular/installer' repository GPG keys ...gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
OK: Checking for apt signed-by key support ...
OK: Importing 'modular/installer' repository GPG keys ...
OK: Checking if upstream install config is OK ...
**NOPE: Installing 'modular/installer' repository via apt ...
^^^^: ... Could not install the repository, do you have permissions?
!!!!: Oh no, your setup failed! :-( ... But we might be able to help. :-)
!!!!: 
!!!!: You can contact Modular for further assistance.
!!!!: 
!!!!: Last 20 log lines from .csm_setup_4jPtAxgH2 (might not be errors, nor even relevant):
!!!!:
!!!!: > ii  gnupg                             2.2.19-3ubuntu2
!!!!: > all          GNU privacy guard - a free PGP replacement
!!!!: > ii  gnupg-l10n                        2.2.19-3ubuntu2
!!!!: > all          GNU privacy guard - localization files
!!!!: > ii  gnupg-utils                       2.2.19-3ubuntu2
!!!!: > amd64        GNU privacy guard - utility programs**
```

NOPE: Installing 'modular/installer' repository via apt. is the problem from Modular?

if not, what's the solution??

Answer (score 0):

yes it is issue from mojo server , you still try again later later use moduler install mojo
then set path variable by command that will appear after installing mojo successful and you will get welcome to Mojo argument

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).